# retreiving values from a for loop and dynamically adding them to a JSON in an array

Tags: jquery, json, for-loop

So I have a for-loop which returns for each result record a

id
Name
StartDate
EndDate

here it is the for-loop below >

```
     for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {   
     }
```

So at the end depending on how many records returned I am going to have a few of these.

What I do want to do is as these records are created dynamically in the loop add them to a json object of mine

```
  jsonObject= [{
  id: 0, name: Name1, series: [{ start: Startdate1, end: Enddate1  }],
  id: 1, name: Name2, series: [{ start: Startdate2, end: Enddate2  }],
  id: 2, name: Name3, series: [{ start: Startdate3, end: Enddate3  }],
  }];
```

So through the loop the id's 1 get added within the object, then 2 then 3.
I've been reading up on the .push method but not sure how I structure this one.

Answer (score 2):

This should accomplish what you're looking for.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/raw/master/json2.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var data = {};
        data.d = {};
        data.d.results = [
            ["1", "Bob", "01/01/2007", "12/31/2010"], 
            ["2", "Jim", "01/01/2007", "12/31/2010"], 
            ["3", "Tom", "01/01/2007", "12/31/2010"]
        ];

        var jsonObject = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {   
            var jsonItem = {};
                jsonItem.id = data.d.results[i][0];
                jsonItem.name = data.d.results[i][1];
                jsonItem.series = [];

            var jsonSeries = {}
                jsonSeries.start = data.d.results[i][2];
                jsonSeries.end = data.d.results[i][3];

            jsonItem.series.push(jsonSeries);
            jsonObject.push(jsonItem);
        }  

        alert(JSON.stringify(jsonObject));
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please explain the significance of data.d.results ? Is it always two dimensional matrix ?

Comment: `data.d.results` is simply the object structure that the OP provided in his question so I used the same structure in my answer. In this instance, `results` is assumed to always be a two dimensional matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You can use $.map() to make transformations like that simple.  This assumes you're receiving an array of objects with properties id, Name, StartDate, and EndDate:

```
var jsonObject = $.map(data.d.results, function(item, i) {
  return {
    id: i,
    name: item.Name,
    series: [{ start: item.StartDate, end: item.EndDate }]
  };
});
```